# Transforming data when saving and reading from database

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have this model (not real code):

```
class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(...)
    mentions = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

content can for instance be:

> Say hi to @Adam and @Bernard

During the Message model save(), "Adam" and "Bernard" are extracted from the text, and their respective user instances added to mentions, so that

```
 >>> m = Message.objects.create(content="Say hi to @Adam and @Bernard")
 >>> m.mentions.all()
 >>> [User: Adam, User: Bernard]
```

Now, as to my problem:

How do I cope with Bernard performing a sex-change and renaming himself Bernarda? I would very much like the content then to read `Say hi to @Adam and @Bernarda`.

Basically, I've tried a strategy of replacing names with ID's when saving (`Say hi to @Adam and @Bernard` then becomes `Say hi to @1 and @2`, i.e. their User.pk's). This works fine when saving, and OK-ish when reading.

Doing this replacement in the model's save() method works fine, but read and lookup operations are a major problem. I cannot find an easy way of making sure that what is stored in the database (ie `Say hi to @1 and @2`) 'magically' becomes `Say hi to @Adam and @Bernard` whenever it is being queried (be that through .filter() and related operations) or its instance being evaluated.

I'm unsure whether I'm on the right track here; any pointers or ideas to doing this differently are very welcome!

Comment: Good question, but can you give an example of what type of filter you are trying to achieve? Why is it necessary to have the names in the string when filtering, if you already have the mentions available in another field?

Comment: The filter (or any query) would come in handy when checking for uniqueness for example: in my case, I don't want two messages that are exactly alike.

Comment: Then why not pass unique=True to the content CharField constructor ?

Comment: Indeed, I can't think of a real-world example where I'd really filter on (part of) the content. Let me think about it a bit more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Write a custom model field class**, that extends CharField, you should overread [the documentation first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.get_prep_value) so that you have an idea of what's there,
2. that **metaclass** = models.SubfieldBase is required for the custom Field to call the custom to_python method
3. **Override to_python()**, [it takes a database value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) and should return a python value, there you can replace @1 by the username of User #1 (say @Adam or @Bernarda),
4. **Override get_prep_value()**,  [it takes a python value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python) and should return a value for the SQL, there you can replace @Adam by the pk of User Admin (say @1),
5. **Query on mentions**, for example `Message.objects.filter(mention=someuser)`, or make another field: one that contains the replaced version and one that contains the possibly out of date usernames - i don't recommend the latter
6. **You could also query on content**, for example `Message.objects.filter(content__contains='@1')`

**Voodoo doesn't do any good in general**, i would make a model method `get_content_display()` that does the replacement, and a templatetag that displays the html version of the content - since your probably want to link @Adam to his user page anyway. I would stick to this because that's [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

**CREDITS to LaundroMat** for debugging this answer and fixing it (there was 2 errors and 1 inaccuracy, which he debugged and came back to report !!!). Also **DO UPVOTE HIS COMMENT** unless you have better way to reward him. Rock'on.

Comment: Boy, am I glad I wrote a plethora of tests first... You should emphasize in 1. that `__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase` is required for the custom Field to call the custom to_python method. I'll accept your answer, but I'm still struggling with to_python, as that method gets passed messages with ID's in them as well as 'name-based' ones. (I've solved it by trapping an error, but unless I forbid usernames consisting solely of integers, it's a bit of a hack). Oh - a final thing; isn't to_python from DB->Python and get_prep_value from Python->DB?

Comment: I want everybody to read the above comment. Because it's not possible to read it and not upvote it. Obviously you deserves a reward for your attitude. Hell I'd invite you to a couple of glass of very fine Single Malt wisky or 18 years old dominican Rhum and [self censored]. NOBODY experimented with SO can say they see such an attitude any often. I hope one day I can claim having such skill and attitude. You my friend, have what it takes to be a real hacker. I wish your were my boss.

Comment: Another thing, please post the minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem in another topic; and **very particularly** it looks more or less like either a bug or a documentation issue. Please forgive that I never had to actually use this technique so of course I'm full of * when i try to explain it, thanks for the acceptance xD

Comment: Are you saying that it's not expected behaviour for to_python() to receive "full-name"-messages and get_prep_value() to receive "id"-messages? I'll try and find a code example (but don't expect it in the first few days, there's some festivities to attend to first). Thanks for the kind words by the way :)

Comment: I just realized that the docs say that `to_python()` "converts a value as returned by your database (or a serializer) to a Python object". The Hand example in the docs also take into account that the value passed is already an instance of Hand (and therefore not a database value).  So I guess it's expected behaviour; I'll stick with my hack of not allowing usernames consisting of nothing but integers.